# Adding custom widgets to a QScrollArea in pyqt5 does not make scrollbar appear

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

The example shown below adds a very simple custom pyqt5 widget to a QScrollArea. When i move the custom widget "off" the area of the scroll area I would expect that scrollbars should appear. Obviously this is not the case.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QApplication, QScrollArea
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPen
import sys

class ExampleWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawWidget(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawWidget(self, qp):
        qp.setPen(QColor(255, 0, 0))
        qp.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100)

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.widget = ExampleWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.widget.setGeometry(250, 150, 100, 100)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can I make the scrollbars appear once a widget is moved so it's not visible completely anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that samples `ExampleWidget` is a child of `QScrollArea`: `self.widget = ExampleWidget(self.scrollArea)`, that does not imply that the widget is handled with the properties of the `QScrollArea`, the `QScrollArea` has a `viewport()` that is the background widget and the `QScrollArea` only shows a part of it. So if you want a widget to be inside you have to use the `setWidget()` method. On the other hand that `viewport()` has the size of the content and how it calculates that size ?, by default it uses the `sizeHint()` of the widget, and in your case it does not have it so it will not show what you want.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ExampleWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        self.drawWidget(qp)

    def drawWidget(self, qp):
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(500, 500)


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.widget = ExampleWidget()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! Seems what I really wanted is a Widget that provides the space to scroll around and where the custom widgets get painted on, example code now looks like this: https://pastebin.com/x1LZbkZB
Hope I'm not reinventing the wheel here ;P

Comment: Thanks for your help, both with the answer and the hint about accepting it!

Comment: Does this code works with multiple widgets?